# PHP Curl post not working, nothing in post

Tags: php, curl

I have two sites on the same server:

api.mysite.com
john.mysite.com

On my API site, I have a service that accepts a POSTed json array.  In my john.mysite.com site I'm calling the service and posting it using:

```
 $info['id'] ="oo_".uniqid();
 $info['version'] ="5";

 $url = "http://api.mysite.com/services/addclient";
 $posted_fields = json_encode($info);

   $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   echo $result;
```

When this is called, I'm not getting anything posted to the webservice.  I've gone into that code and dumped out $_POST and it's empty.  Why isn't the curl sending the data via POST?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that you are `json_encode`ing the data instead of form encoding it.

Another is that `$info` might not be initialized.

Another is that you typo'd `$postfields` on line 9.

Try:

```
$info['id'] ="oo_".uniqid();
$info['version'] ="5";

$url = "http://api.mysite.com/services/addclient";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($info));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: This works, however, I was using json_encode as I need to send the data in json format.  I actually want the info array to go over as json.  I added the json header but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If you send it in JSON, then it won't be in the PHP's `$_POST` array.

Comment: So how can I send the data?  The webservice looks in the $_POST param for the variable and then json_decodes it to convert it to an array.

Comment: The above code will properly send the data so `$_POST` will be properly populated on your other server.  Then it can properly `json_decode` it.

Comment: Thanks Levi, I finally figured out what was happening!

Answer (score 1):

Typo in line 9

```
$postfields
```

should be

```
$posted_fields
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a typo from my putting the code into stack overflow, it was actually right in the code.